# how to use Iterator in object arraylist

Tags: java

Here I got

```
public class Planet
{

    ArrayList<Person> person  = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Person> itr = person.iterator();

    public String getFemaleName()
    {

        for (int a = 0;a < person.size();a++)
        {
            if (person.getGender == "female")
            {
                return person.get(a).getName();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm having 2 problems, 1st is i just want return female's name,but it seems I have to return something even there is no female in my ArrayList.
2nd is how to use an Iterator instead of using a for loop.

Comment: Do you need to use the `Iterator` explicitly, or is it enough if you use the [enhanced for-loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) which uses `Iterator` internally?

Comment: What's the requirement for what you need to return when you don't find find a female?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the case when no female is present , simply putting a `return null` in the end of the function will do the job, because your first `return` statement won't be executed at all.
2. For the second question, using an iterator .. just replace your `for` loop with

   `while(itr.hasNext())
   {
   Person newPerson=itr.next();
   if(newPerson.getGender().equals("female")
   return newPerson.getName();
   }`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Person p : persons) // you should name your lists with plural
{
    if (p.getGender().equals("female")) // use .equals() to compare strings, since == works in weird ways
    {
        return p.getName();
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Its always suggested to use literals on the LHS for equals comparison like `"female".equals(p.getGender())` to avoid NullPointerException issue

Answer (score 0):

Advanced for loop:

```
for(Person person: persons)
   if(person.getGender.equals("female"))
      return person.getName();

return null;
```

Iterator:

```
Iterator<Person> personsIter = persons.iterator();
while (personsIter.hasNext()) {
    Person current = personIter.next(); 
    if(person.getGender.equals("female"))
       return person.getName();
}
return null
```